# Converting Cypher queries to gremlin

Tags: cypher, gremlin, janusgraph

I am converting the cypher queries to gremlin with the help of [Cypher for gremlin](https://github.com/opencypher/cypher-for-gremlin) project.
Followed all the steps to configure it but facing the below issue when running the cypher queries.

```
301195 [gremlin-server-worker-1] INFO  org.opencypher.gremlin.server.op.cypher.CypherOpProcessor  - Cypher: MATCH (n) RETURN n
301209 [gremlin-server-worker-1] INFO  org.opencypher.gremlin.server.op.cypher.CypherOpProcessor  - Gremlin: g.V().project('n').by(__.valueMap().with('~tinkerpop.valueMap.tokens'))
301209 [gremlin-server-worker-1] WARN  io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline  - An exceptionCaught() event was fired, and it reached at the tail of the pipeline. It usually means the last handler in the pipeline did not handle the exception.
java.lang.NoSuchFieldError: scriptEvaluationTimeout
        at org.opencypher.gremlin.server.op.cypher.CypherOpProcessor.handleIterator(CypherOpProcessor.java:197)
        at org.opencypher.gremlin.server.op.cypher.CypherOpProcessor.lambda$evalCypher$0(CypherOpProcessor.java:132)
        at org.opencypher.gremlin.server.op.cypher.CypherOpProcessor.inTransaction(CypherOpProcessor.java:146)
        at org.opencypher.gremlin.server.op.cypher.CypherOpProcessor.evalCypher(CypherOpProcessor.java:132)
        at org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.server.handler.OpExecutorHandler.channelRead0(OpExecutorHandler.java:67)
        at org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.server.handler.OpExecutorHandler.channelRead0(OpExecutorHandler.java:43)
        at io.netty.channel.SimpleChannelInboundHandler.channelRead(SimpleChannelInboundHandler.java:99)
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:379)
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:365)
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:357)
        at io.netty.handler.codec.MessageToMessageDecoder.channelRead(MessageToMessageDecoder.java:103)
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:379)
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:365)
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:357)
        at io.netty.handler.codec.MessageToMessageDecoder.channelRead(MessageToMessageDecoder.java:103)
```

Any help is appreciated if anyone knows or have worked on project

Answer (score 2):

Looking at the queries (both the Cypher and Gremlin) as well as the error, this appears to be an issue where the query timed out trying to return an answer and the Cypher for Gremlin library does not handle it gracefully.

More importantly, the query you are trying to run is not a good query to experiment on, as it is the equivalent of asking an RDBMS to return all rows from all tables.  Even with a small graph and a fast database this query will take a while to return,  I suggest you add some filtering criteria or a limit such as these:

```
MATCH (n) RETURN n LIMIT 10

//substitute appropriate labels and property names    
MATCH (n:foo) WHERE n.name='bar' RETURN n
```

Comment: I have tried out the recommended queries with limit & return but facing the same issue only.

Comment: Are you able to run the Gremlin directly by connectiong via something like Gremlin Console?

Comment: Yes i am able to run the gremlin queries. Even when i run the cypher to gremlin converted query(as logged in error message) which is "g.V().project('n').by(__.valueMap().with('~tinkerpop.valueMap.tokens'))" from the gremlin console it works.